# homegroup access through multiple wireless routers

Tags: networking

I have two wireless routers connected to each other at home. I have a homegroup established in one of them. I want the computers connected to the other router to be able to "see" the homegroup. Is there a way to do that on Windows 7?

Comment: How are your routers connected? Are they 2 access point sharing the same SSID?

Answer (score -1):

What I am guessing you are trying to do is extend your wireless coverage area? i.e. you have a router in your basement and you ant to have access to your basement's computers from the first or second floor.

You need only 1 "router" by router I mean a device which is going to handle the DNS (coverting names to IP : google.com -> 74.125.228.40) and DHCP (taking care of distributing the IP address into your local network) services.

The other device will act as an extension of the first one. That device will be call 4 ways, depending on their action :

Access point (AP) : distributing network from cable to wireless.
exemple : you plug the router by cable into the access point and the AP send the signal wirelessly.

Bridge : taking a wireless signal and coverting it to cable.
Exemple : your neighbor takes your wireless network and plug his computer into the bridge with a cable

Repeater : repeat a wireless signal into the same wireless signal (strengthen the signal)
Exemple : you have a very weak signal from your basement wiresless router and you want to strengthen it for your second floor wireless computer

Switch : wire to wires
Exemple : you have a router with only 1 out and you have 4 computer to wire in it. The switch convert 1 cable into 4 or more

So depending on your settup you may need one of those 4, plus a router. Severals router has the ability to switch from router function to one of those options. You need to check the configurations page. You might not need to replace one of your current device.

In anyway, I hope this help.

antoine